# In search of understanding a typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

I have a program where I'm dynamically loading a dll and using a 'factory' function to get a class instance.  (I actually pulled this from a post I read somewhere on the Net and just blindly used it.)  To do this, I have a code snippet like the following:

```
typedef IHermes* (*pHermesFactory)();

pHermesFactory pHermes = (pHermesFactory)GetProcAddress(hInstance, "HermesFactory");
```

My question is - what does that last line become after the typedef 'replacement'?  When I tried to figure it out by hand I came up with:

```
IHermes* (*pHermes)() = (IHermes* (*GetProcAddress(hInstance, "HermesFactory"))();
```

Does anyone know if this is right?  I really don't **NEED** to know, but I'd like to understand typedef's a bit better.

Comment: Typedefs are not replaced like macros. There is no typedef replacement. And nobody wants to read the "replaced" (as you put it) version of that line anyway because it's completely unintelligible. Better stick with the `typedef`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the typedef, you need to specify the `pointer to function` both as the type of the variable and as the cast, so you'd end up with something like this (I've separated into a definition and assignment in the hope of slightly improved clarity).

```
IHermes* (*pHermes)();

pHermes = (IHermes*(*)())GetProcAddress(hInstance, "HermesFactory");
```

Those can be combined into one horrible mess though:

```
IHermes* (*pHermes)() = (IHermes*(*)())GetProcAddress(hInstance, "HermesFactory");
```

Comment: Wow this does compile.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!  I was wondering if the parentheses from "(pHermesFactory)" would limit the typedef.

Comment: @pelya: I'm relieved to hear it. I hadn't gotten a chance to test, and my confidence in typing this in correctly the first time is somewhat limited. :-)